# Hide the list/s from the user group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, development

I have to hide some **lists/Document Libraries / Picture Libraries** from the particular user group/members.
Eg. I have to hide the **Contact Details List** from the **Editors Group**.
So how to fix it **with OOTB & Custom development** for the both the solutions-**Farm Solution and Office Online**?

Comment: There is no `Deny`-permission level on SharePoint at site level. At CA it can be used, but a permission setting at site level will not override a permission setting configured at CA. Consider your hierarchy and/or user permission policies (to stop inheriting of permissions to the lists/libraries in question).

Answer (score 0):

On each library you would have to break permission inheritance and remove the editor-group from accessing the library. However, if these users are members och the Visitor Group with read permission, they would still be able to access content with read permission.

Comment: Can we do this with dynamically, instead of going to list/library settings and do it manually, can we do that by default?
Eg. If user A have created list/Libraries are hidden to Group-Y.
Is it possible? How?

Comment: @Ram Not out of the box. Question is why you really need it?

Comment: Even if the user have the rights but I don't want to show some lists to particular user group because of different different departments.
I have an option for that with the Sub-Sites.
But still looking for the root site, either it's manageable or not?

Comment: @Ram I would rethink the Information Architecture you're using. Either a user have the permission to access a library and edit its items, or the user hasn't. Making changes to the structure of libraries, even if you can, isn't a good strategy and will be hard to maintain in the future.

Comment: Can you please let me know the right approach to do the same?